# JSP form value not populating in Struts Action class

Tags: jsp, struts

I am new to Struts. I am stuck with a problem. I am trying to populate the JSP form values in to Action class, but I am not getting the values in Action class . Can someone tell me whats is the issue? Here is my JSP.

addEmployee.jsp

```
<a:form action="addEmployee">
<a:textfield name="eId" size="20" label="EmployeeID"/>
<a:textfield name="eName" size="20" label="EmployeeName"/>
<a:textfield name="eCity" size="20" label="EmployeeCity"/>
<a:submit value="ADD EMPLOYEE" ></a:submit>
</a:form>
```

My Action Class -- AddEmployeeAction.java

```
package com.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class AddEmployeeAction extends ActionSupport{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int eId;
String eName;
String eCity;


public AddEmployeeAction(){
}

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("*******Execute*******"+eId+eName+eCity);
    return "success";

}
public int geteId() {
    return eId;
}

public void seteId(int eId) {
    this.eId = eId;
}

public String geteName() {
    return eName;
}

public void seteName(String eName) {
    this.eName = eName;
}

public String geteCity() {
    return eCity;
}

public void seteCity(String eCity) {
    this.eCity = eCity;
}

}
```

My configuration file -- struts.xml

```
<struts>

<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />


<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="addEmployee" class="com.action.AddEmployeeAction">
        <result name="success">/response.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/addEmployee.jsp</result>
    </action>
 </package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getters and setters are named incorrectly; they should follow JavaBean naming convention:

```
public String getEName() {
    return eName;
}

public void setEName(String eName) {
    this.eName = eName;
}
```

Personally, I would either:

1. Name them better, e.g., `empName`, `employeeName`, or
2. Expose an employee and use `employee.name` etc. in the form, or
3. Use `ModelDriven<Employee>`

Unrelated, but labels should be human-readable, e.g., "Employee Name", instead of camel-cased Java-esque strings.

Comment: thanks a lot Dave. It is working now. I am using Eclipse and I automatically generated the getters and setters. I did not notice the naming convention. Thanks...